# Creating anonymous functions via macros

Tags: elixir

I'm tying to make an API where an anonymous function are composed from macros, e.g.

```
transform [x, y], do: x + y
transform x,      do: x
```

should use the `transform` `head` and `body[:do]` as the heads and bodies for an anonymous function. For example, the above macro calls The example above should be collected into:

```
fn [x, y] -> x + y; x -> x end
```

With unquote fragments it's easy to create new named function `def`s, but not new anonymous functions:

```
iex> val = 1
iex> fn() -> unquote(val) end
** (CompileError) iex:99: unquote called outside quote
(elixir) src/elixir_exp_clauses.erl:23: :elixir_exp_clauses.clause/5
(elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:33: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_fn.expand/3
(stdlib) lists.erl:1237: :lists.map/2
(elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:36: :elixir_fn.expand/3
```

Here's my current progress:

```
defmacro anonymous_fn(parts) do
  quote bind_quoted: [parts: parts] do
    fn_branches = for {head, body} <- parts, do: {:->, [], [[head], body]}
    unquote({:fn, [], fn_branches})
  end
end
```

However, the nested unquote fails with the same `unquote called outside quote` error.

At this point I'm just going to use a plain anonymous function, the macro approach was overkill, but I'd still be interested to know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At this point I'm just going to use a plain anonymous function, the macro approach was overkill, but I'd still be interested to know if this is possible.

This is exactly what I was going to propose. :) The anonymous function is much simpler and it also makes the scoping rules clear, works nice with composition and so on.

unquote fragments are really a convenience for defining module functions, they do not apply for any code exactly because it then becomes impossible to know when the unquote fragment applies. For example, if you had this:

```
def foo do
  fn -> unquote(bar) end
end
```

How do you know if it is meant to apply to `foo` or to the anonymous function? In any case, to answer your question, you need to define the code explicitly in the quote:

```
defmacro anonymous_fn(parts) do
  fn_branches = for {head, body} <- parts, do: {:->, [], [[head], body]}
  {:fn, [], fn_branches}
end
```

Or:

```
defmacro anonymous_fn(parts) do
  fn_branches = for {head, body} <- parts do
    quote do: (unquote(head) -> unquote(body))
  end
  {:fn, [], fn_branches}
end
```