# How to create an Anonymous function with a guard using macros?

Tags: elixir

I have been working on a macro to generate anonymous functions dynamically. The function should have 2 clauses. The first clause returns TRUE when the guard is satisfied. Whereas, the second one is the default, which will return FALSE if there is no a match with the first clause. For example:

```
fn 
  xfield when xfield > 2 -> true
  _ -> false
end
```

Here is my macro prototype

```
defmacro condition_function(field, guard) do
  clause1 =  quote do: (unquote(field) when unquote(guard) -> true)
  clause2 =  quote do: (_ -> false)
  fun_clauses =  clause1 ++ clause2
  {:fn, [], fun_clauses}
end
```

The problem is that the first clause never match. This is the input that I have been using to test my macro in Elixir's REPL:

```
iex(84)> myfield = quote do: xfield
{:xfield, [], Elixir}
iex(85)> myguard = quote do: xfield > 2
{:>, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [{:xfield, [], Elixir}, 2]}
iex(86)> myFun = Builder.condition_function(myfield, myguard)
#Function<6.50752066/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(87)> myFun.(2)
false
iex(88)> myFun.(5)
false
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to the help of the guys on the slack channel and CoderDennis's tip.

It was a misconception on my part. I didn't need the use of macros. I just needed a regular function.

Here is the final version of my function to create anonymous functions with a guard:

```
def anonym_function(field, constraint) do
    clause1 =  quote do: (unquote(field) when unquote(constraint) -> true)
    clause2 =  quote do: (_ -> false)
    fun_clauses =  clause1 ++ clause2
    {fun, _} = Code.eval_quoted({:fn, [], fun_clauses})
    fun
end
```

Sorry for my misunderstood :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer yet, but here's how to see the AST your macro is returning:

```
defmacro condition_function(field, guard) do
  clause1 =  quote do: (unquote(field) when unquote(guard) -> true)
  clause2 =  quote do: (_ -> false)
  fun_clauses =  clause1 ++ clause2
  result = {:fn, [], fun_clauses}
  IO.inspect(result)
  result
end
```

Here's what I get from just quoting the anonymous function within iex. This is probably what the macro should generate:

```
iex> quote do: fn
...> xfield when xfield > 2 -> true
...> _ -> false
...> end
{:fn, [],
 [{:->, [],
   [[{:when, [],
      [{:xfield, [], Elixir},
       {:>, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [{:xfield, [], Elixir}, 2]}]}],
    true]}, {:->, [], [[{:_, [], Elixir}], false]}]}
```

Here's what I get when actually executing the macro with the `IO.inspect` in it:

```
iex(9)> myFun = Builder.condition_function(myfield, myguard)
{:fn, [],
 [{:->, [],
   [[{:when, [], [{:myfield, [line: 9], nil}, {:myguard, [line: 9], nil}]}],
    true]}, {:->, [], [[{:_, [], Builder}], false]}]}
```

(Line 9 is referring to the line number within iex.)

This tells us that `unquote(myfield)` and `unquote(myguard)` aren't doing what you expect them to do within your macro.

I'm not enough of a macro expert to know how to do what you're trying to do, but just wanted to share my macro debugging tip for now. If I can figure out the way to make it work, I'll share that also.

Comment: Thanks for your tip and time! This is my first time working with Elixir's Macro System.

Comment: I tested the body of my macro function on iex, and I get the right AST. I don't now what I'm missing in my macro function :(

Comment: I am using this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849774/creating-anonymous-functions-via-macros) as guide, but seems that I'm doing something wrong

Comment: If I use a normal function (def) instead a macro (defmacro), I get the right representation of the anonymous function. But, wow can I get the reference to that function from its AST and call it ?